# How can you throw an existing exception while preserving its stack trace in VB?

Tags: vb.net, exception, stack-trace

If I have an existing exception object (I'm *not* in a catch block, I just happen to have been given an exception object), is there any way (re)throw it while preserving it's stack trace?

The context for asking is that I'm writing a RunWorkerCompleted handler. If an error happened while running the background task, then this will have shown up in the Error property of the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs. To keep the code simple I want to use the same error handling code to trap this, or any error that happens later during the handler. That means I need code like this:

```
Private Sub OnDone(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)

Try
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then Throw e.Error ' But how do I keep its stack trace?
        ' do other work that might throw an exception
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' handle any exceptions
End Try

End Sub
```

I don't think that using an InnerException here (ie. saying something like Throw new Exception(ex)) will work because then I have the problem that my Catch block has no way of knowing whether the exception it's supposed to be handling is the outer one or an inner one.

StackOverflow seems to have various similar questions, but I've not found anything that describes this particular situation.

Comment: Why do you need to rethrow it? Could you not just write your error handling code for this particular exception within that if statement, thus conserving the stack trace?

Comment: The error handling code for the exception in the If statement is identical to the error handling code that'll go in the Catch block, so while I could just repeat the code in both places that's not really ideal - will make code harder to read.

Comment: What about having the error handling code in a separate function, which you call from both locations? Alternately, have an error variable and a foundError variable, and set these two in the if and catch statements and then handle the error after the try-catch block.

Comment: Thanks Miika. Those are both possibilities that will work. Both lead to code that I think would feel uglier/more complex than it ought to be, but it may well be that those are the best solutions.  I thope not though.  A separate function sounds simple but it turns the one-line If e.Error ... Throw ... line into four lines / If e.Error Then / Call ExceptionHandler() / Return / EndIf. And that in almost all my RunWorkerCompleted handlers (Several dozen of them)

Comment: Yup, fair point about it not being terribly elegant. Looking into it further, I did find this post: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/01/02/rethrowing-exceptions-and-preserving-the-full-call-stack-trace.aspx   Although the problem in your case is that you have already taken the exception "out of its context" so to speak, while the example does the "preserving" within the original catch.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature in .NET 4.5 that will do what you want. But since that won't help you now, your only option is to wrap it in another exception.